# Principal Components and Dot Product

Tags: vector-analysis

Suppose we have three 5 explanatory variables $X_1, \dots, X_5$. The first principal component is the linear combination $$Y = \epsilon_1 X_1+ \cdots + \epsilon_5 X_5$$

that maximizes $\text{var}(Y)$. Can we write this as $$Y = \mathbf{\epsilon} \cdot \textbf{X}$$

that is in vector notation?

If we wrote both $\mathbf{\epsilon}$ and $\textbf{X}$ as column vectors, would we write it as $$Y = \mathbf{\epsilon}^{T} \cdot \textbf{X}$$

Comment: In the usual vector notation, for column vectors $v$ and $w$, $v\cdot w$ is shorthand for $v^Tw$ (note the absence of the $\cdot$ in the second expression). This is in accord with the usual convention for matrix multiplication, where we simply write $AB$ to indicate the product of $A$ and $B$. Since $v^T$ is a $1 \times n$ vector, and $w$ is $n \times 1$, the multiplication is implied.

Answer (score 0):

A *caveat*:  $X$ is an $n\times 5$ matrix, where $5$ is the number of features and $n$ are the observations. Then each eigenvector $\epsilon^i$ $i=1,\dots,5$ of the covariance matrix considered in the OP is a vector of length $n$. In this notation
$$Y=\epsilon^T X$$

is a $(5\times n)\times (n\times 5)=5\times 5$ matrix (with PCA you get a dimensional reduction of your problem) obtained by the product of matrices. Denoting by $Y^i$ the $i$-th row of $Y$, then

$$Y^i=\left(\epsilon^i\cdot X_1,\dots,\epsilon^i\cdot X_5\right)$$

where the $i$-th eigenvector $\epsilon^i$ is the $i$-th row of $\epsilon^T$ and $X_j$ denotes the $j$-th column of $X$, i.e. the column of the $j$-th feature.

Comment: So $Y$ is the first principal component for all observations?

Comment: sorry @bvect: I edited my answer to expand notation.

Comment: I think $n$ should be the number of observations and $5$ the number of attributes.

Comment: ...but you wrote 5 explanatory variables $X_1$...$X_5$: explanatory variable= variable in your OP, am I right?

Comment: Suppose the five variables are: height, weight, income, blood pressure, and body temperature. These are the number of attributes. We would have 5 attributes for each observation.

Comment: I see now: "variables" are those I called attributes, while "observation" is what I called variable :). I will edit my answer changing variable<->attribute.